# How to save values on each form submit without overriding saved datas?

Tags: forms, configuration

i am having a form with 2 values to save on submit:

```
 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($_POST['op'] == 'Import Accounts') {
      $filter = $form_state->getValue('ldap_filter');
      \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('amu_import_ldap.settings')
        ->set('ldap_filter', $filter)
        ->save();

      $roles = $form_state->getValue('roles_list');
      \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('amu_import_ldap.settings')
        ->set('roles', $roles)
        ->save();       
      }
```

It is working but each save override the previous one.

How can i structure the yml to save a list of datas iterately

/config/install/my_module.settings.yml

```
ldap_filter: ""
roles: null
```

i have been trying a schema file although i am not sure it if it is considered at all

/config/schema/my_module.schema.yml

```
amu_import_ldap.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'couple filtreLDAP / roles'
  mapping:
    ldap_filter:
      type: text
      label: 'Filtre LDAP'
    role:
      type: array
      label: 'Rôles'
```

i have seen things like

> node.type.*:

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config items can be arrays, so something like this should work. (Note that I haven't actually set it up to try it).

```
      $new_filter = $form_state->getValue('ldap_filter');
      $filters = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('amu_import_ldap.settings')
        ->get('ldap_filter');
      $filters[] = $new_filter;
      \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('amu_import_ldap.settings')
        ->set('ldap_filter', $filters)
        ->save();
```

Of course that's a very naive example, you may wish to check you are only adding unique items to the array, and so on.

Comment: thanks the same simple solution stroke my mind overnight :)